# Something wrong with contract ABI and decoding input data using web3.py

Tags: web3.py, proxy-contracts

I'm trying to decode some input data for this contract  `0x24b22b031ae1b5a6b09f9a0fd33613a40e0d70e6`, from this tx [0x30e2451138e443bcf69f59858df52eff647710dfa244d9b0e84c79504bb72fa5](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x30e2451138e443bcf69f59858df52eff647710dfa244d9b0e84c79504bb72fa5) (though the problem exists for any tx's I select for the given contract)

I'm running the following code to try and decode the input:

```
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi)
res = contract.decode_function_input(input_data)
```

Where the ABI and the input data are directly copied from etherscan for that transaction. When I run the above I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\ethereum\controllers\eth.py", line 108, in decode_input_data
    return contract.decode_function_input(input_data)
  File "C:\...\env\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\env\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 465, in decode_function_input
    func = self.get_function_by_selector(selector)
  File "C:\...\env\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\env\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 458, in get_function_by_selector
    return get_function_by_identifier(fns, 'selector')
  File "C:\...\env\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 1679, in get_function_by_identifier
    'Could not find any function with matching {0}'.format(identifier)
ValueError: Could not find any function with matching selector
```

I'm assuming this error means that the input data doesn't match up with the ABI, but I'm not sure why. I've tested my code with some other random tx's and contracts and it decodes them fine- so I'm pretty sure it has to do with the contract itself. Am I using the wrong contract's ABI? and if so, how would I go about figuring out what contract I should actually be using?
Thanks!

Comment: |Am I using the wrong contract's ABI?" It is impossible to tell, as you did not have your ABI in the question, or larger context what are you trying to do and why.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I explained that I was using the ABI from etherscan for that contract- which can be found here https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0x24b22b031ae1b5a6b09f9a0fd33613a40e0d70e6